# Spring-orm 5x version

Tags: java, applicationcontext, spring-orm

Currently, I am converting the spring-orm 3x version to 5x. and Hibenate 3x to 5x. My applicationcontext.xml file have a configuration

```xml
<property name="typeDefinitions">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.TypeDefinitionBean">
                    <property name="typeName" value="varchar_enum" />
                    <property name="typeClass"
                        value="xxx.xxx.xxx" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.TypeDefinitionBean">
                    <property name="typeName" value="trimmed_string" />
                    <property name="typeClass"
                        value="xxx.xxx.xxx" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
```

Comment: Spring 5 doesn't support hibernate 3 (which is what the exception is clearly telling you as well). You need to upgrade to Hibernate 5 as well and use the Hibernate way of registering custom types.

Comment: Yes. I updated to Hibernate 5x.

Comment: Then you need to ditch this and use the Hibernate5 way of registering custom types.

Comment: Ok. TypeDefinitionBean class is deprecated. Could you please tell me what I need to use instead of that?

Comment: The regular way of HIbernate to register those, as documented by Hibernate.

Comment: Which is by using the `@Type` annotation on the fields that need it.